# Click website button and scrape the result

Tags: vba, excel, web-scraping

I am writing where I can execute a form on a website through a macro. I am able to open up internet explorer and pass all the variables correctly however when it comes time to submit, I am a bit lost.

```
Sub ESTRAI()
    Dim objIE As Object
    Dim objElement As Object

    ' Create InternetExplorer Object
    Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    ' Make sure the Internet Explorer window is visible
    objIE.Visible = True

    ' Navigate to your URL
    objIE.Navigate "https://www.trainline.eu/search/milano/roma/2017-02-16-06:00"

    ' Wait while IE loading...
    Do While objIE.Busy
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 3, Now)
    Loop

    ' Get the button
    Set objElement = objIE.Document.getElementsByClassName("search__button ember-view progress-button")
    ' Click the button
    objElement.Click        

End Sub
```

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [mcve].* - you haven't described any specific problem or error; what's the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the "0" at the end of your object element.

```
Sub ESTRAI()
Dim objIE As Object
Dim objElement As Object

' Create InternetExplorer Object
Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

' Make sure the Internet Explorer window is visible
objIE.Visible = True

' Navigate to your URL
objIE.Navigate "https://www.trainline.eu/search/milano/roma/2017-02-16-06:00"

' Wait while IE loading...
Do While objIE.Busy
    Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 3, Now)
Loop

While objIE.Busy
    DoEvents
Wend
Do Until objIE.readyState = 4
    DoEvents
Loop
stop
'Get button and search
objIE.Document.getElementsByClassName("button progress-button--button")(0).Click

End Sub
```

Comment: i pokemon_man the your modify code not run. The problem is on the Get button and search
objIE.Document.getElementsByClassName("button progress-button--button")(0).Click

Comment: Perhaps explain a little exactly what the difference is between that code dump and the OP's code? Readers usually don't have a built-in diff viewer.. and code dumps make quite poor answers, prompting copy+paste without understanding what's happening, or learning anything new.

Comment: @cory what you mean it does not run, runs perfectly fine on my end. The reason your code did not run is because you did not specify the "(0)" after setting your object element.

Comment: I tried to run the code on Excel, and fails to click on search and then perform the search.

Comment: put a break point or type "stop" before the get button and search code and see.

Comment: Many thanks pokemon_man.the code run You're great!!. I need still to learn well the code vba for web scrape hmtl page. Many thanks- Domenico

Comment: Dear pokemon_Man. I tried to copy entire content table after press button but  i can not to copy the contents on the worksheet. Can you help me?

Comment: which contents?

Comment: for example the price on the table  or time table

Comment: You should ask a new question.